# Show div on hover span styling

Tags: css, html

The title may be a bit misleading.

http://jsfiddle.net/whb8A/

I have a h3 element inside a span tag and of course it shouldn't go there, however I cannot seem to style the spanned text in the div in the manner I want.

If you hover over the image in the jsfiddle, the hidden div is shown and that is exactly what I want it to look like but if I take the h3 tag away from the text I can't seem to style it with CSS.

Should I be looking at a Jquery alternate? If so any tutorials of guides would be great, thanks

UPDATE: Thanks for all the help so far but I don't think I've explained very well.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/827/examplewc.jpg/

The left side is how I would like it to be styled however removing the h3 tags and removing h3 from the class .info causes it to be styled as on the right side. It's the border width, postion and padding I am concerned about the most

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the problem you seem to be having... see this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/whb8A/3/

Comment: Is that "white bar" (border) supposed to be there?

Comment: what's wrong with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yrsHv/)

Comment: I should be more specific. On the original fiddle, when the black div is shown with the text, there is a 5px border underneath the text that runs the width of the div. The margin and padding on the .info h3 styles the border but without the h3 tags the border just runs along the bottom of the black div with no margin

Comment: @luca, the only problem is the code isn't proper and it doesn't validate. I was just hoping there would be a correct way of doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested I solved the problem.

Instead of using the h3 tags and a span, I removed both and instead put a div inside the div that appeared on hover. You can see what I mean in the below fiddle. Now validates in html5 which is what I was after, thanks for all the help

http://jsfiddle.net/whb8A/62/

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to put the text style definitions directly under the `<a>` tag, so as to override the default anchor tag styling. Example:

```
.featured a {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All I see when I drop the `<h3>` tag is a loss of margin around the text. If you want that back, simply replace the `<h3>` with a `<span>`, change the CSS to match that instead of the `h3` and add `display: block` to the rule.

Answer (score 0):

You have this near the end of your CSS:

```
.item a:hover .info {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 30px;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #000;
}
```

This will select all `.info` elements inside of hovered `a` tags inside of a `.item` element, but in your HTML you have **no .item element**

Remove `.item` from the CSS and all is well when you remove the `H3`

Comment: .item was used for the span class?

Comment: Apologies, .item shouldn't be in the css code. But if I remove the h3 tags from the html and from the .info h3 class http://jsfiddle.net/whb8A/34/ the border is not styled as it was before